# Can't build/run Jetpack Compose Multiplatform's desktop version, even on brand new projects on the latest version of IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

Basically title, I can run Jetpack Compose Desktop projects, but not the desktop part of JCMP, although the Android part runs fine.
Clicking the build button does nothing as well.

[image: The run configuration]

[image: Common's Gradle file]

Android and Desktop's gradle are unchanged from the project creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Compose Gradle plugin as described https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Getting_Started and run using Gradle task runner as well.